# Express : Cannot Find Module?

Tags: node.js, express

I am using Express to do some routing, and I want to call a function inside a static javascript file from `signup.js`, but I get an error saying

```
Error: Cannot find module './js/list.js'
```

My directory structure is as follows:

```
app.js
-routes/signup.js
-public/js/list.js
```

In my `app.js` file, I have this line:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

In my `signup.js`, I have:

```
var listModel = require('./js/list.js');
```

My `list.js` file contains:

```
module.exports.list = function (userName, category) { 
  return ({
    "owner" : userNameName,
    "category" : category,
    "completed" : [],
    "planned" : [],
    "current" : [],
    "dropped" : [],
    "onHold"  : []
  });
}
```

Is there anything else I am missing in order to import the list function into my signup file? Thanks!

Comment: It looks to me that from `routes/signup.js` you would need `require('../public/js/list.js);`

Comment: Oh wow, thanks, that worked!

Answer (score 0):

Since they have different `signup` and list have different parent directories, the NodeJS require function will not consider them siblings. Thus you need to write

```
var listModel = require('../public/js/list.js');
```

inside of `routes/signup.js`

If you had a file `public/test.js` you could indeed use

```
var listModel = require('./js/list.js');
```

to require the dependency from within it.

Answer (score 0):

The require module path should be:

```
var listModel = require('../public/js/list'); // it is fine to have the file extension
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case since `signup.js` is in a different folder than `list.js`, you have to specify the full path to it.

`var listModel = require('../public/js/list.js');`

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` means that when you go to `localhost`(or whatever route the app is hosted on) you will have access to that folder. So that means when you go to `localhost:3000/js/list.js` you will have access to the folder.